# jQuery hide/show , alert not working for the first time but works perfect from the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

[image: My page should be like this on start]

My page should be like this on start

and when I select the check box the text box should appear otherwise it should be hidden.

[image]

I'm loading my javascript in the beginning of an html.

my javascript looks like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    if($('#user_tech_know').is(':checked')) 
        $('#user_tech_areas').show();
    else 
        $('#user_tech_areas').hide();

    if($('#user_other').is(':checked')) 
        $('#user_other_areas').show();
    else 
        $('#user_other_areas').hide();


$(":checkbox").change(function(){
    if($('#user_tech_know').is(':checked')) 
        $('#user_tech_areas').show();
    else 
        $('#user_tech_areas').hide();

    if($('#user_other').is(':checked')) 
        $('#user_other_areas').show();
    else 
        $('#user_other_areas').hide();

    if(($(":checkbox:checked").length)> 3)
alert('Sorry, maximum 3 boxes may be checked.');


});


if(($(":checkbox:checked").length)> 3)
alert('Sorry, maximum 3 boxes may be checked.');
     });
```

Hide/Show and alert are not working for the first time. But working perfectly from the second time.

No idea where I'm going wrong. Is it because of document.ready(function())?

My HTML looks like this.

```
   %script(src ="/app/assets/a.js")
   %h1 Mentee Registration

  .row
   .col-md-6.col-md-offset-3
     = form_for(@user) do |f|
       = render 'error_messages'
       = f.label :'Mentee Information'
       = f.label :'Cisco Email'
       = f.email_field :cisco_email
       = f.label :'Current group'
       = f.text_field :current_group
       = f.label :'Current work location,city'
       = f.select :work_city, options_for_select(%w[Bangalore-India Chennai-India Hyderabad-India SanJose/Milpitas SanFrancisco Ottawa RTP Switzerland]), include_blank: true
       = f.label :'Developmental goals ,  check at least one box that apply, can select max 3 choices from the list below'
       = f.check_box :conflict_resolution
       = f.label :conflict_resolution, 'Conflict Resolution'      
       = f.check_box :customer_know_how
       = f.label :customer_know_how, 'Customer Know How'
       = f.check_box :exec_acheive_results
       = f.label :exec_acheive_results, 'Executive to achieve results'
       = f.check_box :personal_branding
       = f.label :personal_branding, 'Personal Branding'
       = f.check_box :leading_change 
       = f.label :leading_change, 'Leading Change'
       = f.check_box :align_and_influence    
       = f.label :align_and_influence, 'Align and Influence'
       = f.check_box :managing_without_authority
       = f.label :managing_without_authority, 'Managing Without Authority'
       = f.check_box :win_win_negotiation
       = f.label :win_win_negotiation, 'Win-Win Negotiation'
       = f.check_box :career_exploration
       = f.label :career_exploration, 'Career Exploration'
       = f.check_box :effective_communication
       = f.label :effective_communication, 'Effective Communication'
       = f.check_box :think_out_box
       = f.label :think_out_box, 'Creative Thinking/Think Out Of the box'
       = f.check_box :tech_know
       = f.label :tech_know, 'Technical Know-How, List Areas'
       = f.text_field :tech_areas
       = f.check_box :other
       = f.label :other, 'Any Other'      
       = f.text_field :other_areas
       = f.submit "Register Me", class: "btn btn-primary"
```

Comment: Add `alert($('#user_tech_know').length)` before the if condition in the dom ready handler

Comment: can you please put a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for it?

Comment: I'm just trying to hide/show text boxes and displaying an alert message when the number of checkboxes exceeds 3. I think adding that line wont help. @ArunPJohny

Comment: I've added screenshots. Does it help ? @Manoz

Comment: @Novice screenshots are of not much help... you need to share the html

Comment: we need html to debugg it is display block and none issue so can you please give as html

Comment: included HTML file @KevalBhatt

Comment: What actually happened is your html looks scary. Me and I suppose everyone here are addicted to traditional html structure. What view engine you use?

Comment: This is haml code (html.haml). I'm using ruby on rails. @Manoz

Comment: @Novice did you add it inside the script block?  `<script>script here</script>`